Is it possible to compute $A \mathrm{diag}(v_1) A \mathrm{diag}(v_2) A\ldots$ faster?
Is it possible to somehow compute a matrix $M$ of the form
$$
M = A\ \mathrm{diag}(v_1) A\ \mathrm{diag}(v_2) A\ \mathrm{...}\ A\ \mathrm{diag}(v_n) A
$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ (and is diagonalizable) and $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$ faster than with the naive $O(nm^{\text{matmul power}})$ algorithm? Maybe with some specific type of $A$ (I can change it to some extent)?

Is $A$ symmetric?

@BrianBorchers no, and I can't make it so, unfortunately.

Do you need $M$ element by element, or is it enough to just be able to compute the action of $M$ on a vector?

@WolfgangBangerth Hello! Actually, now I only need to compute $Mx$ with a few different $x$ vectors, so yes, action would be sufficient. But then the question is whether is it possible to compute it in less than $O(nm^2)$.

That seems unlikely. You can't beat $O(nm^2)$ if you had different matrices instead of the same $A$ every time, simply because that's how long it would take to read all of the matrix entries. At least for $n\ll m$, I see little hope that you could beat that bound.

@WolfgangBangerth actually $n$ is much larger than $m$, in my case
